# How to use an array to find and compare similarly named objects and then update objects?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to simplify my VBA code to use arrays rather than a bunch of if/then statements.  I have a bunch of labels in a VBA form that are similarly named such as `mortgageTotalLbl` and `mortgageRunningLbl`.  I want to compare the two values and highlight the `RunningLbls` when they are greater than or equal to the appropriate `TotalLb`.

I have tried using the code below but the color does not get updated on objects when the condition is true.  It also does not give me any errors when run.

```
Sub Update_Colors()

Dim account As Variant
Dim allaccounts As Variant
Dim var1 As String
Dim var2 As String
Dim currentaccount As Variant

allaccounts = Array("mortgage", "electricity", "phones", "internet", "garbage", "water")

For Each account In allaccounts
    var1 = account & "RunningLbl"
    var2 = account & "TotalLbl"
    currentaccount = var1
    If var1 >= var2 Then
        currentaccount.ForeColor = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    End If
Next account

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

var1 is a string so when you assign currentaccount = var1, currentaccount is a variant/string not a label on your form. You have simply gotten the name of the label to color.

You need to get the labels and compare their Captions not their names. I have assumed the Captions are Double and so force the captions to double. You'll get an error if the captions cannot be coerced to Double (or whatever type they are in your situation).

You'll also get errors if there are no labels with the names being used.

```
Dim myForm As frmTheFormWithTheLabels
Set myForm = New frmTheFormWithTheLabels
Dim myLabel1 As Control
Set myLabel = myForm.Controls(currentaccount)
Dim myLabel2 As Control
Set myLabel2 = myForm.Controls(var2)
If CDBL(myLabel1.Caption) >= CDBL(myLabel2.Caption)
    myLabel.ForeColor = RGB(0,200,0)
Else
    'Make the color something to represent the less than condition
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Can you show me how to incorporate my loop into your example code so that it runs against all the entries in my array?

Comment: @BrandonLB all of the code I wrote goes in your loop to replace your If/EndIf block EXCEPT the form declaration and setter. You should also set the objects to Nothing before you exit your procedure. The form declaration and setter needs to be outside your loop.

Comment: It is close but not quite right still. If I put the actual label name ```mortgageRunningLbl``` in a ```MsgBox```, I get the appropriate value, but the value within the loop keeps showing a 0. I am at a loss since ```mortgageTotalLbl``` returns the correct information but ```mortgageRunningLbl``` doesn't. I also reversed the labels and still get 0 for the new label that represents ```mortgageRunningLbl```. ```mortgageTotalLbl``` is set equal to a cell value on a spreadsheet but I set the value of ```mortgageRunningLbl``` by using ```Application.SumIfs```.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: @BrandonLB when you do Msgbox mortgageRunningLbl what you are actually doing is Msgbox mortgageRunningLbl.Caption (Caption is the default member of Label). Post your current code.